# VBA code issue for copying and pasting same columns from multiple sheets in excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Having a problem with the code.

The excel workbook has 4 sheets.  The workbook is regularly updated.

-Sheet1 is where I want the data pasted to.

-Sheets2-4 have the data that I am trying to get.

-The range "A2:B2" is where the data is at in Sheets2-4.  Data needs to be pasted in the same range in Sheet1.  No data pasted.

The below code results in A2:B2 only selecting in Sheet2-4 and the same range being selected and copied in Sheet1.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub test()

    Worksheets.Select
    Range("A2:B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you going to overwrite the target range in sheet 1 or do you mean to paste to the next available row? You will need a loop as a minimum to cycle through sheets 2-4.

Comment: No overwriting will occur.  The file that has the data is updated weekly.  Each week I will have a new file to work so the goal.  I was hoping to get a command that would work, create the .bas to import at the time of use to get the updated data.

Comment: but you say you are copying the same range from sheets 2-4 into the same range in sheet1. If they are all the same range there has to be an overwrite. Or is there a defined range into which all this data fits? If so where? Gather the ranges together from 2-4 and paste to range A2 sheet 1?

Comment: Sheet1 won't be saved to the document and isn't on the updated workbook.  I am only using Sheet1 to gather data to send to another program. Say the workbook was updated today.  My goal was to open the workbook, create Sheet1 and then import the .bas file to pull the data.  Next week comes, update occurs, what I did today won't be on the updated workbook that comes next week.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is copy/pasting from sheet1 to sheet1.

1. The first line of your code selects all sheets.
2. Then it selects the current range of first sheet, and applies the same selection to all sheets.
3. When you copy the selection on multiple sheets, only first sheet gets copied.
4. Then you paste the sheet1, to sheet1.

   - You cant copy from multiple sheets in one command.
   - If you could, then pasting values from 3 sheets into the same destination range in 1 sheet is also not possible.

Your questions states that you only need range A2:B2, but your code selects the used range below the code which is unnecessary if you only need range A2:B2.

Here is some code to copy/paste from a single sheet:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B2").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B2")
End Sub
```

if you would prefer copying the activesheet, then remove the sheet reference from the above code:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Range("A2:B2").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B2")
End Sub
```